# How to print the following sequence, while satisfying these conditions

Tags: java, algorithm

This was actually an interview question. I had to print the following using Java:

```
9
9 8 9
9 8 7 8 9
9 8 7 6 7 8 9
. . .
. . .
```

During the interview, I wrote an embarrassing piece of code, but it worked nonetheless - using an outer loop, **two** inner loops (one for the decrementing sequence and one for the incrementing sequence!) and a ton of variables. One of the variables was the length of each row.

The interviewer asked me to try and rewrite it using

- just one outer and one inner loop
- *without* the row length variable.

*Note: After looking at the answers, I think the interviewer didn't really mean the second condition. He might have just wanted me to simplify my code and the second point just bumbled out of his mouth.*

So, later back home, I arrived at this:

```
int rowCnt = 5;

for(int i = 1; i <= rowCnt; i++)
{
    int val = 9;
    int delta = -1;
    int rowLen = i * 2 - 1;

    for(int j = 1; j <= rowLen; j++)
    {
        System.out.print(val + " ");

        val += delta;

        if(j >= rowLen / 2) delta = 1;
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

Here, I am using just one inner loop. I'm using a `delta` value to determine whether increment or decrement happens. For each row, I compare the current index to the midpoint of the row and change the delta.

I satisfied the first condition - just one inner loop. But I am not able to do it without using the row length.

**How can we print this without finding out the row length?**

*Many answers were acceptable, But I had to choose one, and picked the one that was simplest to understand for me.*

Comment: Try `StringBuilder`:`reverse` and `append`, and a single decrementing int...

Comment: you can't just substitute actual expression(statement) in place of `rowLen`?

Comment: Note that you decrement `9` `currentRow - 1` times. You can use this instead of the row length. The two are related though, so it seems like a silly requirement not to use the row length, but whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They probably wanted to hear the word '**recursion**'.

Here's a recursive solution that doesn't need length:

```
countDownInMiddle("", 9, "");

private static void countDownInMiddle(String start, int n, String end) {
    if (n < 0) {
        return;
    }
    System.out.println(start + n + end);
    countDownInMiddle(start + n, n - 1, n + end);
}
```

Comment: nice. I was thinking there's a more succinct way but couldn't wrap my head around it...

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
    int start = 9;
    for (int i = 0; i <= start; i++) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder((start - i) + " ");
        for (int j = start - i; j < start; j++) {
            sb.insert(0, (j + 1) + " ");
            sb.append((j + 1) + " ");
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is simple PHP, hope logic is clear and easily portable to Java:

```
$rowCount = 10;
$startNum = 9;

for ($idx =0; $idx <$rowCount; $idx ++) {

    for ($jdx=0; $jdx < (2*$idx +1); $jdx++) {

        if ($idx < $jdx)
            echo $startNum -(2*$idx) + $jdx.' ';
        else
            echo $startNum - $jdx.' ';
    }
    echo '<br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Pyramid {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int start = 9;
        String left = "";
        String right = "";
        for (int i=start; i>=0; i--) {
            System.out.println(left+i+right);
            left = left+i;
            right = i+right;
        }
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
9
989
98789
9876789
987656789
98765456789
9876543456789
987654323456789
98765432123456789
9876543210123456789
```

This iterative solution is equivalent to the recursive solution. I would prefer to use iteration over recursion since the extra stack memory needed by the recursive solution could be huge when the number of rows grows big.

Answer (score 0):

My non-recursive solution:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 2*i+1; j++)
            System.out.print((Math.abs(j - i) + 9 - i) + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }
```